# How do I convert double to unsigned for currency?

Tags: c, double, precision

I know there are issues with accuracy with doubles, but this situation surprised me.

I read some doubles from a file.  These are the values:

```
90.720000 33.800000 43.150000 37.970000 46.810000 48.770000 81.800000 19.360000 6.760000
```

Since they represent currency, they always have up to 2 decimals of precision.  I want these values to be stored as unsigned values.  So, I multiplied them all by 100.0, and cast them in an unsigned array.

When I print the unsigned values, I got this:

```
9071 3379 4314 3796 4681 4877 8179 1935 675
```

Why do some of these numbers have errors and some don't?  Is there another way around this? Why would the code tell me it has the value 90.72, if it really has 90.71?

As requested, here's the relevant code:

```
unsigned itemprices[MAXITEMS];
unsigned u_itemweights[MAXITEMS];
double itemweights[MAXITEMS];

numberofobjects=0;
do{
    fscanf(fp, " (%*u,%lf,$%u)", &itemweights[numberofobjects], &itemprices[numberofobjects]);
    numberofobjects++;
    if(fgetc(fp)==' ') continue;
    else break;
}while(1);

puts("\nitemweights before convert:");
for(i=0; i<numberofobjects; i++) printf("%f ", itemweights[i]);

//  convert itemweights to unsigned.
for(i=0; i<numberofobjects; i++) u_itemweights[i] = itemweights[i] * 100.0;

puts("\nitemweights after convert:");
for(i=0; i<numberofobjects; i++) printf("%u ", u_itemweights[i]);
```

Here's an output sample:

```
itemweights before convert:
90.720000 33.800000 43.150000 37.970000 46.810000 48.770000 81.800000 19.360000 6.760000
itemweights after convert:
9071 3379 4314 3796 4681 4877 8179 1935 675
```

Comment: Seems you're casting the numbers in a "truncated" way, not "rounding". `So, I multiplied them all by 100.0, and cast them in an unsigned array.` Please show some of your code.

Comment: **Never use floating point for precise calculations like currency!** Read the description of the C tag carefully!

Comment: @Olaf: But that's what the OP wants to do: To convert fractional dollar amounts to pennies to get rid of the problems with floating-point values.

Comment: @MOehm: The problem already starts reading the value using floats. Correct way is to read them as two unsigned values (integer.fraction) and combine later. (or just do not use a decimal point in the input format at all as WeatherVane states)

Comment: @KorganRivera you forgot to post the code that creates the problem.

Comment: How do you know that you only need two places of precision?

Comment: @MOehm That's actually what I'm about to do.  I was just throwing this question out there in case I had overlooked a simpler solution.

Comment: @Olaf: Yeah, yeah. Still there's no need to chide the OP (in bold face, even) for something he's aware of and just doesn't know how to achieve.

Comment: @Olaf The values seem to read well.  The file contains "90.72" and when I read it and printf it, I get "90.7200000".  So that seems to work.  But after multiplying it, the value changes.  That's what doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @WeatherVane Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: @KorganRivera, no they aren't right. The imprecision when printing things out need much more digits to be visible.

Comment: @JensGustedt Ah, ok.  That's frustrating.

Comment: @MOehm: If he were aware, he would not have that problem, Make it simple - ok - but not too simple

Comment: @Olaf Disagree with "Never use floating point for precise calculations like currency!".  1) Directing what not to do is not so nearly useful as suggesting what to do.  2) Using FP with currency, like many programming problems, has its pitfalls, like rounding errors - especially for learners.   A knowledgeable programmer can code successfully using `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real value is `90.719999999999998863131622783839702606201171875`. If you multiply by `100` the result is `9071.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875` and casted to an integer  leads to `9071`.

Example: http://ideone.com/QQ7Ddm

You can add `0.5` (or any other small number < 1) to the result of the multiplication before you cast it to an integer.

Another option would be the use of the `round` function.

Comment: Oh that's correct. I thought it was `float`. (It was not me who gave the downvote.)

Comment: Multiplying `90.719999999999998863131622783839702606201171875` by `100` actually produces a double with value exactly `9072`. There must have been some additional source of error somewhere.

Comment: @mch That's what confused me.  If the real value is 90.7199..., then why would it tell me the value is "90.72000000000" ?

Comment: I suspect `9071.99` would suffice for purposes of example? Considering a `long long unsigned` will have a maximum of `1.8447e+19`, all digits beyond that are suspect.

Comment: @KorganRivera because `90.719999999999998863131622783839702606201171875` rounded to 11 decimal digits is `90.72000000000`. You can print it with `printf("%.80f\n", number);` like I did in the example.

Comment: @user2357112 please take a look at the example, if you save `90.72` to a double variable, multiply this variable with `100` and cast to `unsigned`, the result would be `9071`.

Comment: @mch: I think we're seeing the effects of 80-bit extended precision. [My own test results](http://ideone.com/hLW4Wo) show that the result is exactly `9072`, but if the compiled code converts an extended-precision intermediate value directly to an integer, that would produce 9071.

Comment: @user2357112 I learned that every exact `double` number is also exact as an `long double`.

Comment: @mch: But not vice versa. The mathematically exact value of `90.719999999999998863131622783839702606201171875*100` may be representable in extended precision, but converting it to an IEEE754 double produces exactly `9072`.

Comment: Corner case failure with "add 0.5 (or any other small number < 1) to the result of the multiplication before you cast it to an integer." fails for the the FP number just before 0.5.  `volatile double x = nextafter(0.5, 0.0);   volatile double y = x + 0.5;   printf("%.17e %d\n", x, (int) y);` typically produces `1` rather than the desired `0`

Comment: @chux you forgot to multiply by `100` before adding the `0.5`. It is a solution to this specific problem. A double number with 2 significant decimal digits will never end up with `.5` after multipying with `100`, but with `.9999999` or `.00000001` or similar.

Comment: Agreed - with currency values near a multiple of 0.01.

Answer (score 2):

Given a file with the values you quote, this prints them in cents with the same 2 decimal digits in cents.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *inf;
    unsigned cents;
    double money;
    if((inf = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        return 1;
    while (fscanf(inf, "%lf", &money) == 1) {
        cents = (unsigned)(money * 100.0 + 0.1);
        printf("File %f, cents %u\n", money, cents);
    }
    fclose(inf);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
File 90.720000, cents 9072
File 33.800000, cents 3380
File 43.150000, cents 4315
File 37.970000, cents 3797
File 46.810000, cents 4681
File 48.770000, cents 4877
File 81.800000, cents 8180
File 19.360000, cents 1936
File 6.760000, cents 676
```

**Edit** for unbelievers who commented. This takes the maximum 32 bit `unsigned` cents, converts to `double` dollars, and back to cents without loss. The `double` mantissa has 53 bits, 21 bits more than `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    double money;
    unsigned cents = UINT_MAX;
    printf("cents = %u\n", cents);
    money = ((double)cents) / 100;
    printf("money = %.2f\n", money);
    cents = (unsigned)(money * 100.0 + 0.1);
    printf("cents = %u\n", cents);
    return 0;
}
```

Progam output:

```
cents = 4294967295
money = 42949672.95
cents = 4294967295
```

Comment: This works.  All my numbers are coming out correctly now after the conversion.  It's frustrating that this is even an issue in C.

Comment: @Jason please give an example where it fails. `double` has greater significance than 32-bit `int`.

Comment: Any value that converts from decimal to binary floating point with a thousandths decimal smaller than 9 (after multiplying by 100 in binary floating point).  Even adding 0.5 won't necessarily give a correct result.

Comment: @Jason *any value*? These don't. I asked for an example please.

Comment: It would take a while to construct the actual counter example.  I admit, with fewer bits in the fixed point than the floating point mantissa, there may not be a counter example.  Without a formal proof, I'm still be hesitant to use this code over parsing the digits manually.

Comment: @Jason the proof is simple. I ran a loop testing every 32-bit `unsigned int` apart from `UINT_MAX` in my above snippet, without a fault.

Comment: It is probably correct, but it potentially munges the double value in the conversion.  It's still vastly simpler and safer to just parse the decimal value.

Comment: @Jason the same also works with div 10000, the "cents of cents" mentioned in another answer. But the question was about values that are *already* in decimal point format (to 1 cent significance), something I would never advocate.

Comment: I included code to parse without using floating point in my answer as well (in case there's a need for 64 bits).

Comment: @Jason agreed - 64 bits is where it falls down.

Comment: @WeatherVane I just got a moderator message about my "edit".  I had my phone in my pocket with the SO app on it, and it managed to press edit and paste random stuff in your answer!  I apologize profusely.  I had no idea what you were even talking about since it was fixed by the time I pulled my phone out again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm honestly a little disappointed to see people encouraging parsing the values to floating point and doing *any* math on those values.

There are two issues.  The first is that decimal values aren't representable in fixed precision floating point.  For example, 0.01 is not representable in floating point.

The next issue is fundamental to multiplication and division.  Both change the number of digits after the decimal.  Fundamentally you can not have infinite accuracy with any finite precision data type like `double` or `uint32_t`.

Decimal values (like currency) can be handled using fixed point arithmetic, but accuracy will still be lost in calculations.

For example, 1% of $0.50 would be $0.005 and rounded up to $0.01.  However, with fixed point arithmetic using two places of precision...

```
 0.50
x0.01
----- 
=0.00
```

Here, the result is $0, but the actual value should be $0.01.  And, if this is multiplied by 25 (e.g. compound interest), the result is now off by 2500%.

For posterity, here's the code to read values without using floating point.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc]) {

  unsigned dollars = 0;
  char dimes = 0;
  char pennies = 0;

  unsigned fixed = 0;

  FILE* values;

  values = fopen("values", "r");

  while (fscanf(values, "%u.%c%c%*i\n", &dollars, &dimes, &pennies) != EOF) {

    dimes -= '0';
    pennies -= '0';

    fixed = (dollars * 100) + (dimes * 10) + pennies;
    printf("$%u.%u%u -> %u (cents)\n", dollars, dimes, pennies, fixed);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

outputs...

```
$90.72 -> 9072 (cents)
$33.80 -> 3380 (cents)
$43.15 -> 4315 (cents)
$37.97 -> 3797 (cents)
$46.81 -> 4681 (cents)
$48.77 -> 4877 (cents)
$81.80 -> 8180 (cents)
$19.36 -> 1936 (cents)
$6.76 -> 676 (cents)
```

Comment: You make valid points about floating-point precision and that using fixed-point notation won't automatically solve all your problems. Unfortunately, the code you posted "for posterity" scans the given input (with sub-penny precision), but little else. It also misprints values like "1.02" as "1.2".

Comment: @MOehm You're absolutely right, the printing was done incorrectly (updated).  I explicitly didn't include a generalized version since two places of precision were what the OP stated they were working with.

Answer (score 1):

if those doubles you're reading from the file are in text format (you didn't specify) then rather than read them into doubles then cast, you can read it as text and parse the text manually. (eg remove the period and skip the zeros and then convert to uint

Comment: Yeah I thought of that.  I was just hoping it wasn't necessary, and that instead I'd overlooked something basic.  Thanks!

Comment: @if you're working with stock price data, they you'll actually find that they are regularly quoted in 4 decimal places.  So you may want to keep that in mind and do "cents of cents", in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do some of these numbers have errors and some don't? Is there
>   another way around this? Why would the code tell me it has the value
>   90.72, if it really has 90.71?

The answer to your question has to do with how floating point numbers are stored in memory. Floating-point values are stored in memory in *IEEE-754 single-precision* (`32-bit float`) or *IEEE-754 double-precision* (`64-bit double`) floating-point format. The format (in binary) is comprised from a 3-part encoded number where the most significant bit (31 or 63) is the `sign bit`, the next 8 or 11 bits (float/double) are an exponent in excess format, and finally the next 23 or 52 bits (float/double) are the normalized mantissa/significand.

For example your *double* value of `90.72` is stored in memory as:

```
 IEEE-754 dbl  : 0100000001010110101011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110
                |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
                |s|   exp    |                     mantissa                      |
```

The format allows the storage of all floats or doubles within their respective ranges in 32 or 64 bits in memory, respectively. However, the formats suffer from a limitation on accuracy imposed by the limited number of bits available.

You can best understand this limitation by considering the binary number that represents each floating point value. In memory, it is nothing more than a `32-bit` or `64-bit` sequence of `'0's` of `'1's`. Since the number of bits taken by each format (single/double precision) is the same as the number of bits used by an `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` (or `unsigned long long` on some hardware), for every floating-point value, there is an unsigned int or unsigned long with the *exact-same* binary representation in memory.

This will help expose why some of your numbers have errors and some don't. If you consider the equivalent unsigned integer for your double value of `90.72`, you will see that there is a limitation on how `90.72` can be represented in IEEE-754 double-precision format in memory. Specifically:

```
Actual Value as double, and unsigned long equivalent:

 double        : 90.7199999999999989
 long unsigned : 4636084269408667566
 binary        : 01000000-01010110-10101110-00010100-01111010-11100001-01000111-10101110
```

Here is where considering the *unsigned long* equivalent helps. What is the next possible larger number that can be represented in memory? (*Answer:* `1` more than the current value of the *unsigned long* equivalent)

```
Closest next larger value:

 double        : 90.7200000000000131
 long unsigned : 4636084269408667567
 binary        : 01000000-01010110-10101110-00010100-01111010-11100001-01000111-10101111
```

(**note:** this change of `1` in the *unsigned long* equivalent (or change in *one-bit* in memory) only effects the value out near the 13th decimal place, but can have huge consequences if you attempt to multiply by `100.0` and cast as you have found)

Looking at how your current double of `90.72` is stored in memory, and the next possibe larger value that can be stored, should show you clearly why *some of your values have errors and some don't.*

If any given double value is one represented in memory by a value slightly less than the currency value (e.g. `90.719...` instead of `90.720...`), you will *create rounding error* by using your *multiply by 100.0 and cast* approach. That's why you are better served using on of the schemes provided in the other answers that is not subject to this type of error and also why you want to avoid (or properly manage) floating-point inaccuracies when dealing with money.

Answer (score 0):

Concert from currency to integers carefully.

1) Scale.
2) Round via `round()`.  Do *not* use +0.5 trick - too many problems.
3) Insure in range.
4) Cast

```
unsigned convert_double_to_unsigned_scaled_rounded(double x, double scale) {
  double x_scaled = x*scale;
  double x_rounded = round(x_scaled);
  assert(x_rounded >= 0 && x_rounded <= UINT_MAX);
  return (unsigned) x_rounded;
}

// u_itemweights[i] = itemweights[i] * 100.0;
u_itemweights[i] = convert_double_to_unsigned_scaled_rounded(itemweights[i], 100.0);
```

A key problem with currency coding is the need for exactness - and this involves rounding to rectify.  A simple `(unsigned) x` will too often have issues - as you have seen - as it truncates the fraction.  Another example: calculating 7.3% on a loan is an issue should code use `double` or integers.